# JPA Entities from Tables turns int primary key to String

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I use Eclipse --> JPA Entities from Tables get generate entities from mysql database. All the tables' primary keys -- ids are int(11) AI PK. So instead of int or long, i am getting String for all the keys. What did i do wrong?

Thanks!

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="LOCATION_ID")
private String locationId;
```

Comment: use " private int locationId; " instead of " private String locationId;  "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse is not correctly parsing your primary key's data type (`int(11)`). As a result, Eclipse is unable to resolve the appropriate data type to Java type mapping. Because that mapping is missing, Eclipse defaults the datatype for primary key attributes to `String`. You could remove the display width attribute from your datatype (i.e. the `(11)`) and Eclipse should be able to more appropriately map the data type.

Comment: Thanks! That's the problem. It looks like MySQL adds the (11) by default. How can I tell MySQL to stop doing it?

Comment: Or how can I tell eclipselink that this is a Int column, not a String column.

Comment: I don't know enough about the Eclipse DTP MySQL driver to know why it sees your column's data type as `int(11)`. How is the column defined in your DDL? To answer it second question: It is DTP (an Eclipse plug-in), not EclipseLink, that is parsing the data type from the metadata returned from MySQL. There is no easy way to configure DTP to do other than what it is doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out when generating the entity, click on the id and eclipselink will allow you to select the mapping type. Choose int instead of String will do the trick.